# What do we call the components in names?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a western name, you usually have a first name, some number of middle names, and a surname (family name). What is the catch-all word for these components?

To give you context: I am writing a function that takes a name and removes unnecessary whitespace between the components, e.g. *John    Smith* --> *John Smith*. I'm writing a comment to explain what the function does, but I can't settle on a good word for these components. Surely there is a word for this?

I know that all these components are *technically* "names", but in this context, writing "removes whitespace between names in a name" seems confusing at best. I've also thought about calling them "words", but again this seems misleading. My current top choice is "components", but this seems overly general.

Comment: maybe just dodge the problem and say "trims internal whitespace in name"

Comment: @Slepz dodging the problem is a good suggestion, but now I'm curious. Surely there has to be some term for the components within a name?

Comment: This is a nice example (unless you have to find a solution, as you do) of the far-too-common problem of polysemy-with-hyponymy. A name consisting of two (or more) names. 'John Smith' is a binomial, but I've never seen 'mononomial' used outside algebra and biology.

Comment: I checked [this onomastic glossary](http://icosweb.net/drupal/terminology) and some relevant Wikipedia articles, and no clear term stuck out. Some WP articles use *element*, the glossary qualifies all the different kinds of names with the suffix *-nym*, and I'm sure I've seen *namepart* before. So there's three options, at least: *[name] elements*, *nameparts*, or simply *nyms*. Or you could stretch things a bit and borrow a productive suffix from linguistic terminology and coin *nymeme* ;)

Comment: @Dan Bron Did I really just upvote a suggestion for a D-I-Y term? I suppose Crystal invented 'lexeme' (but I think others have redefined the term for him).

Comment: If you want to dodge the problem through eloquent obfuscation, just call them anthroponyms

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've always really wanted *lexeme* to mean the individual words in a multi-word set phrase, because morphemes are units of meaning (which compose words) and phonemes are individual sounds (which compose speech), but the word steadfastly refused to mean what I want it to mean.

Comment: @Slepz Unfortunately, "Dan Bron", and "Dan", and "Bron", are all anthroponyms.

Comment: @DanBron Subanthroponyms?

Comment: @Slepz You mean names for troglodytes, like "Thog", as in "Thog smash!"? ;)

Comment: Another way to dodge the question is to phrase it as *remove extraneous internominal whitespace* (or *extranomial* if you also strip leading/trailing whitespace).

Comment: 'Full name' is the entire name. 'First name' 'middle name' and 'last name' or 'family name' are 'parts of the full name'. Why be filled with anxiety about not knowing a single hypernym when you can just describe it in two or more words? This isn't telegraphy which charges by the word.

Comment: @Mitch This is still interesting to know. Bookmarking and +1 to the question.

Comment: i'd use array notation, so we have: names[0], names[1], ..., names[name.length-1]

Answer (score -1):

You may be overthinking this, applying too much attention to the category of words being manipulated (peoples' names) and neglecting that this is a commonly coded function with many other word strings. See, for example, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-lead) on a sister site regarding this problem in a broader context. So, "remove unneeded spaces in word string" would be a general comment in the code for this function.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question posed. Side-stepping the problem is obvious. I'm interested in an actual term to describe the components of names.

Comment: The question posed is an overly narrow focus on a problem with a widely recognized solution. My proposed answer is thus wholly relevant and a universal solution. It doesn't sidestep the problem; rather it places it in a well-recognized programming context. The much narrower question about the components of peoples' names is already widely known as, e.g., first, middle, last, etc. Why needlessly complicate a broader programming function with specifics unique to one set of word strings?

Comment: The context I gave is really unimportant: again, I know how to solve the problem in this context. My question is about the English language, not about solving a minor programming problem. The narrower question about the components of peoples' names is actually *not known*: you resorted to enumerating "first, middle, last." That's exactly the issue: I'm asking for a single word that encompasses all these components. If you read the chain of comments on my original question, you'll find that *namepart/nym/nymeme* were well-received suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I considered the context to be important. I read a lot of code and clear comments are the best and too rare. One focusing on a little-known term for a specific type of word string would be opaque to most. It still is a language problem, and the other options in the comments are of interest, too.

Comment: You can consider the context important if you like, but then you are answering a question that is different from mine. My question is: "In a western name, you usually have a first name, some number of middle names, and a surname (family name). What is the catch-all word for these components?"

Comment: Further: this is not a question about how to write good code comments. If it was, it would be inappropriate for English.SE, and I would be posting on programmers.SE or a similar site instead.

Comment: Hmm. I think it is great to see a possible cross-thread between these types of sites. Insofar as your question arose from the problem stated as "I'm writing a comment to explain what the function does, but I can't settle on a good word for these components," I still think my suggested direction for a possible answer might be helpful to others.